# Finding area on a projected surface

Tags: differential-geometry

To find the area of a region on the surface in $\Bbb R^3$ given by $z=f(x,y)$ we project the surface on the $X Y$ plane by the formula $\iint dS=\iint \frac{dxdy}{|\vec n_1.\vec k|}$. My question is, does the same formula hold for projecting the surface on a different surface say $S'$ by replacing $\vec k$ by the unit normal, $\vec n_2$ of the second surface ($\iint dS=\iint \frac{dS'}{|\vec n_1.\vec n_2|}$?)

Then this can be used to prove that projecting a surface, $S$ of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ on a cylinder $ y^2+z^2=1,-1\le x\le1$ will not change the area of $S'$ on the cylinder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure what you're asking, but:

1. The area of a surface depends only on the surface, not how it is projected.
2. The area of a surface $S_{1}$ can be calculated as an integral over another surface $S_{2}$ by mapping $f:S_{2} \to S_{1}$ and pulling back the area form of $S_{1}$. The resulting formula involves the Jacobian of $f$, however. (When projecting a graph $z = f(x, y)$ on the plane $z = 0$, the Jacobian is the reciprocal of the dot products of normal vectors in your first formula.)
3. If you're trying to prove [Archimedes' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html), it is not enough to project the sphere radially to a circumscribing cylinder and assert "the areas are the same". That happens to be true, but requires consideration of the Jacobian.

Comment: D.Hwang Thank you. I just generalized from the Archimedes theorem so forgot about the Jacobian,again thanks for pointing that. Then can you give me the formula involving the Jacobian.?

Comment: If $dA$ denotes the area form of $S_{1}$, the change of variables theorem reads$$\iint_{S_{1}} dA = \iint_{S_{2}} f^{*}(dA).$$In coordinates, if $(u, v)$ are coordinates on $S_{2}$, and $(x, y) = f(u, v)$ are coordinates such that $dA = dx \wedge dy$, then$$f^{*}(dA) = f^{*}(dx \wedge dy) = (\det Df)\, du \wedge dv.$$

Comment: D.Hwang what is $dx∧dy$? Is $Df$ Jacobian?

Comment: $dx \wedge dy$ is just fancy notation to emphasize that the product $dx\, dy$ is anti-symmetric. $Df$ is the first derivative, i.e., the matrix of first partial derivatives.